# How return value from fetch to outside function in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, fetch-api

i need help with getting data outside the fetch function.

```
const  getSpecies =  (URL) => {
    fetch(URL)
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data =>{
        console.log(data.name);
    })
}
```

I'm fetching data from API to get a one value. I don't know how return this value as a value of function. Always I get a undefined or `[Promise object]`. I tried like that:

```
const  getSpecies = async (URL) => {
    const  data = await fetch(URL);
    const  resoult = await data.json();
    const species = resoult.name;
    console.log(species);// value of name
    return species
}
```

I also tried use few callbacks functions and return in all places.

I still have problems with understand asynchronous JS. That's why I need help.

Answer (score 0):

**async-await** always returns a promise, even when it returns nothing.

Where ever you use getSpecies() function do a `.then()` after it to get data.

```
getSpecies.then(data=>{console.log(data)})
```

And in the first case you have already done correctly. You simply need to return the data :)

```
const  getSpecies =  (URL) => {
    fetch(URL)
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data =>{
        console.log(data.name); // This should get the data here and you can return it here
       return data;
    })
}
```

If your URL is responding correctly, then the above code should work correctly.

Comment: okay but problem is in it that i have someting lik this `        <p class="character__rate">age: ${getSpecies(object.species)}</p>` and i need to return value from this funcion. when i am doing like you said i still have promise object

Comment: Tell me is object.species a URL link. Share that link

Comment: for example https://ghibliapi.herokuapp.com/species/af3910a6-429f-4c74-9ad5-dfe1c4aa04f2

Comment: OK bro, Let me check it, I will let you know what is going on in a moment. Let me test this

Comment: API is working fine. So is the fetch. Let me resolve it for you in Javasript

Comment: Are you working on a simple Javascript Project or React Project. ?

Comment: im working only with JS

Comment: Somebody has closed this question. Yup, I also checked it. Though the data is coming but within our code, data is not avaiable. This may be because of asynchronous behaviour. Could you share all you code on jsfiddle. Or codepen. I will definately help you  :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/226301/discussion-between-imran-rafiq-rather-and-mateusz-lukoszek).